$ 2x_n \leq x_{n+1} + x_{n-1}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*. $ Prove that $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ has a limit.
Problem :
Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ and consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ of real numbers such that
$
2x_n \leq x_{n+1} + x_{n-1}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}^*.
$
Prove that $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ has a limit (that is, not only convergent, the limit can also be $\infty$ or $-\infty$).
My attempt:
The main idea is to prove that the sequence is monotonic, since all monotonic sequences have a limit.
If $x_0 \leq x_1$, then the relation
$
2x_1 \leq x_2 + x_0 \leq x_2 + x_1  \implies x_2 \geq x_1.
$
Now, let's assume that $x_{n+1} \geq x_n$ for a given $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then
$
2x_{n+1} \leq x_{n+2} + x_{n} \leq x_{n+2} + x_{n+1}  \implies  x_{n+1} \leq x_{n+2}.
$
So, by induction, if $x_0 \leq x_1$, then the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is increasing, so it has a limit.
By the same logic, if there exists $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_k \leq x_{k+1}$, the sequence will be "eventually" increasing, and since removing a finite number of terms from a sequence doesn't affect its limit: $ \implies \text{In this case, we also have proved that the sequence has a limit.}
$
In the last case, if there isn't any $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_k \leq x_{k+1}$, the sequence is decreasing, so it also has a limit.
I think I went through all the cases possible, so $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ must have a limit. However, I feel like I missed something. Is my solution and reasoning correct? I am open to any suggestion, comment or alternative solution. Thank you !

This question is similar to: Does a sequence in $\mathbb R$ with this condition $2a_n \leq a_{n-1}+ a_{n+1}$ satisfy this convergence?. I'll explain why : if you assume that the sequence is bounded, then the post's proof works. If you don't, then your statement is wrong as $x_n=n$ shows.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer No, the question in that link is not about $\lim x_n$.

@SarveshRavichandranIyer Also , how is it that $x_n = n$ doesn't work ? It satisfies the inequality ( it isn't strict!! ) and it's limit is +inf so it has a limit.

Your argument is correct. $(x_n)$ is a convex sequence and that is either decreasing everywhere or eventually increasing.

@MartinR thank you for clarifying and now I know that my solution is valid.

@Unknowduck You added the requirement after I set the duplicate. With that in mind, it is no more a duplicate, and the argument as stated is valid.

what are $a,b$ for?

Your approach is correct and can be simplifed slightly. It is sufficient to consider two cases:
Case 1: $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is strictly decreasing. Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists in $\Bbb R \cup \{ -\infty \}$.
Case 2: $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is not strictly decreasing. Then $x_k \le x_{k+1}$ for some $k$. Using the “convexity condition” $2x_n \leq x_{n+1} + x_{n-1}$ and induction it follows that $x_n \le x_{n+1}$ for all $n \ge k$. Then $(x_n)_{n \ge k}$ is increasing and $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$ exists in $\Bbb R \cup \{ +\infty \}$.
Remark: The situation is similar for convex functions $f:[0, \infty). \to \Bbb R$, they are either decreasing everywhere or eventually increasing. In either case, $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ exists in the extended real number line $\Bbb R \cup \{ -\infty, +\infty \}$.
